# Improving the fitting of model by NMinimize

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have written a code in mathematica for a simultaneous system of ordinary differential equations. Though the fitting is just ok, but I want to make it more accurate. 
I am attaching my code here. Could you please give me a suggestion on how to make my model fitting better?
Please note I am a new user of mathematica, and I have prepared this code already with help of a user of this community, so if you suggest a change please clearly mention/highlight it so that I can easily understand it.
I want to use similar fitting procedure as already in code, do I need to add another ODE equation or what?

```
bcdata = {{0, 0.000836}, {1, 0.001650}, {2, 0.002068}, {3, 0.002772}, {4, 0.004730}, {5, 0.005390}, {10, 0.006248}, {20, 0.006336}, {40, 0.006512}, {60, 0.006534}};
aqdata = {{0, 0.003564}, {1, 0.003630}, {2, 0.004818}, {3, 0.005786}, {4, 0.007260}, {5, 0.007964}, {10, 0.008998}, {20, 0.008646}, {40, 0.008492}, {60, 0.008316}};
gasdata = {{0, 0.000000}, {1, 0.000352}, {2, 0.000638}, {3, 0.001188}, {4, 0.001474}, {5, 0.001650}, {10, 0.002684}, {20, 0.003564}, {40, 0.003564}, {60, 0.003916}};
sddata = {{0, 0.017622}, {1, 0.016368}, {2, 0.014476}, {3, 0.012254}, {4, 0.008536}, {5, 0.006996}, {10, 0.004048}, {20, 0.003454}, {40, 0.003432}, {60, 0.003234}};
eqns = {bc'[t] == k1 sd[t] - k4 bc[t], aq'[t] == k2 sd[t] - k5 aq[t], gas'[t] == k3 sd[t] + k4 bc[t] + k5 aq[t], sd'[t] == (-k1 - k2 - k3) sd[t]};
Thread[{aa[t_], bb[t_], cc[t_], dd[t_]} = DSolveValue[{eqns, bc[0] == 0.000836, aq[0] == 0.003564, gas[0] == 0.000000, sd[0] == 0.017622}, {bc[t], aq[t], gas[t], sd[t]}, t]];
model[k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_, k5_] := Sum[(aa[bcdata[[i, 1]]] - bcdata[[i, 2]])^2 + (bb[aqdata[[i, 1]]] - aqdata[[i, 2]])^2 + (cc[gasdata[[i, 1]]] - gasdata[[i, 2]])^2 + (dd[sddata[[i, 1]]] - sddata[[i, 2]])^2, {i, Length@bcdata}]
fit = Last@NMinimize[model[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5], {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5}]
Thread[{k1, k2, k3, k4, k5} = Values@fit];
Show[Plot[{aa[t], bb[t], cc[t], dd[t]}, {t, 0, 60}, Frame -> True], ListPlot[{bcdata, aqdata, gasdata, sddata}]]
```

Comment: Fitting each data set separately results in much better fits.  So it appears that your assumption that there is a common set of parameters does not hold. Maybe just a subset of the parameters might be in common which would result in a better fit.  I'm not seeing that *Mathematica* is doing anything wrong.

Comment: is there any option to restrict the solution to a final value of 'sddata' no less than 0.003234 (@60 minutes) ?

Comment: If somehow we are able to tell in the code that the last four data points in 'sddata' are almost same (not changing), I am sure the whole model will perfectly fit. But I have no idea how to input this information in the code? Can somebody please help?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your code correctly but if the solution for `sd` is `sd[t] -> E^(-k1 t - k2 t - k3 t) sd0`, then doesn't `sd[t]` approach zero quickly?  But `sddata` does not flatten out at zero.  Is that related to a lack of fit?

Comment: No it is not lack of fitting, but I am interested in knowing how can I describe ODE for 'SD' such that it flatten out not at zero but somewhere close to real data (0.0032)

Comment: Cross-posted at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1891390.